# Hahn Banach and dual space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces, hahn-banach-theorem

Let $X$ be a normed space and $X′$ its dual space. If $X≠{0}$, show that $X′$ cannot be ${0}$.

Theorem: For an element $x_0$ other than $0$, there is a functional $f^\sim$ such that the norm is $||f||^\sim=1$ and $||f||^\sim=||x_0||$.

I think I will use this theorem. But how do I prove it, can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How do you prove *what*? The theorem or the statement from the first line?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Hahn-Banach theorem? If so, consider the mapping $\mathbb{K}x_0 \to \mathbb{K}: \lambda x_0 \mapsto \lambda$ and use Hahn-Banach in an appropriate way.

Comment: the statement from the first line. @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: sorry i don't understand the match you said @QuantumSpace